# Links does not work in FIrefox, but in chrome it works perfectly

Tags: html, hyperlink

people. my links do not work properly on firefox, but on chrome they are good. I've tried all the tips from here, but nothing helped. I can't find the issue. I tried to delete #position:relative#, also I've tried to change #z-index#. I don't understand because in chrome it works very well, but Firefox.

```css
table
 {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 transition-duration:1s;
}

body,div
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 
{
 font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: normal;
}
/*-------Resets above-----*/

/*-----Styles for Html website-----*/
#wrapper
 { 
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 background:linear-gradient(#6699ff,#99ccff,#ccffff);
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
#logo
{ 
 
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
 font-style:italic;
 width:1200px;
 height:70px;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 text-align:left;
}

.button 
{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 380px;
 margin-left:1100px;
 width:150px;
 height:75px;
 z-index:1;
 background-image:url('images/new_year_background');
 border-radius:20px;
 border:2px solid #33ff99;
 font-size: 20px;
 transition-duration: 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration:none;
}
 .button:hover 
{ 
 background-color:#33ffff;
}
.button a:hover 
{
    cursor: pointer;
 color:white;
}
/*--------navigation and buttons-----------*/
nav
{ 
 position: relative;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-right:75px;
 z-index:1;
}
.menu1
{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:1350px;
}
.button1
{
 height:50px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:#33ff66;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:1px solid #00cc66;
 color:white;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 display:inline-block;
 transition-duration:1s;
 float:right;
 border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
}

.button3
{
 height:50px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:#33ff66;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:1px solid #00cc66;
 color:white;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 display:inline-block;
 transition-duration:1s;
 float:right;
 border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}

.button2
{
 height:50px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:#33ff66;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:1px solid #00cc66;
 color:white;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 display:inline-block;
 transition-duration:1s;
 float:right;
}
.button1:hover
{
 background-color:#99ff66;
}
.button1 a:hover
{
 color:white;
}
.button2:hover
{
 background-color:#99ff66;
}
.button2 a:hover
{
 color:white;
}
.button3:hover
{
 background-color:#99ff66;
}
.button3 a:hover
{
 color:white;
}
/*------End of the navigation-----*/
#first
{
 border-radius:20px;
 position: relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/symphony.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:10px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;

 
}
#sec
{ 
 color:red;
 border-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/new_year_background.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;
}
#tre
{
 border-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/swirl_pattern.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;
}
#quad
{
 border-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/logo_x_pattern.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;
}
#fiv
{
 border-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/ignasi_pattern_s.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;
}
#sex
{
 border-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/confectionary.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;
}
#sev
{
 border-radius:20px;
 position:relative;
 width: 1300px;
 height:500px;
 background-image:url('images/restaurant.png');
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 border: 2px solid #3366ff;
}
footer  h3
{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
 <title>My Guide to Success</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; scale=1" />
 <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 
 <div class="menu1">
  <nav>
   <button class="button3"><a href="#">Fith</a></button>
   <button class="button2"><a href="#">Fourth</a></button>
   <button class="button2"><a href="#">Third</a></button>
   <button class="button2"><a href="#">Second</a></button>
   <button class="button1"><a href="#">First</a></button>
  </nav>
 </div>
 
  <div id="logo"><h1><a href="#sev">My Guide To Success</a></h1></div>
  <div id="first"><button class="button"><a href="#sec"><h2>Next Step</h2></a></button></div>
  <div id="sec"><button class="button"><a href="#tre"><h2>Next Step</h2></a></button></div>
  <div id="tre"><button class="button"><a href="#quad"><h2>Next Step</h2></a></button></div>
  <div id="quad"><button class="button"><a href="#fiv"><h2>Next Step</h2></a></button></div>
  <div id="fiv"><button class="button"><a href="#sex"><h2>Next Step</h2></a></button></div>
  <div id="sex"><button class="button"><a href="#sev"><h2>Next Step</h2></a></button></div>
  <div id="sev"><button class="button"><a href="#logo">To Top</a></button></div>
 </div>
</body>
<footer>
<h3>Copyright &copy; Marin KapranoFF - 2016</h3>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors inside buttons behave differently in Firefox. I'd recommend removing the `<button>` wrapper and styling the anchor with CSS:

```
<div id="first">
    <a href="#sec" class="your-button-styles"><h2>Next Step</h2></a>
</div>
```

You generally don't need to place a button inside an anchor, the anchor already handles a click event to navigate you to the href.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You solved it so easily. I just registered for first time on this  website and I got answer in just 10 minutes. God bless you)

Comment: Right. It's not just that you don't _need_ to put `a`s inside `button`s, it's actually forbidden to nest interactive elements. `input`s inside `a`s, `select`s inside `button`s, all off limits. If you do that anyway, you will have interoperability issues.